# JQuery - adding multiple values to a single element in a table

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I am using flask.
I pass 4 different lists into the HTML file, loop through them and put their value in the table

```
{% for (s_pid, s_name, s_cpu_percent, s_memory_percent) in zip(pid, name, cpu_percent, memory_percent)%}
          <tr>
            <td id="task-pid">{{s_pid}}</td>
            <td id="task-name">{{s_name}}</td>
            <td id="task-cpu-percent">{{s_cpu_percent}}</td>
            <td id="task-memory-percent">{{s_memory_percent}}</td>
          </tr>
{% endfor %}
```

It looks great and I can see every value in the table clearly

[image]

I need to update these values every 5 seconds and for that, I am using jquery (using ajax just to get the updated value and put in the values below e.g `var task_status_cpu_percent = data["task status cpu percent"];`(list))

```
for(var i = 0; i< task_status_pid.length; i++){
      $("#task-pid").text(task_status_pid[i]);
      $("#task-memory-percent").text(task_status_memory_percent[i]);
      $("#task-name").text(task_status_name[i]);
      $("#task-cpu-percent").text(task_status_cpu_percent[i]);
    }
```

task_status_pid is a list, in fact, all of the task_status are lists in the same length but when the jquery code accrues it doesn't do anything! I tried using replaceWith and that didn't go well
what happened is that all the values were on the first tab.

what do I need to do in order to go through all of the values in task-pd task-name etc' like it is on the loop (`{% for (s_pid, s_name, s_cpu_percent, s_memory_percent) in zip(pid, name, cpu_percent, memory_percent)%}`)

Comment: IDs need to be unique

Comment: @mplungjan what do you mean there are everyone has a different id name

Comment: No. If you have 4 rows, you have 4 times `<td id="task-pid">`

Comment: @mplungjan Oooo I understand so what do I need to do in order to use the jquery on it

Comment: You have to make the IDs not unique. Best would be to use a class

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use class or add a counter to the ID. IDs MUST be unique

So EITHER

```js
{% set count = namespace(value=0) %}
{% for (s_pid, s_name, s_cpu_percent, s_memory_percent) in zip(pid, name, cpu_percent, memory_percent)%}
          <tr>
            <td id="task-pid{{count.value}}">{{s_pid}}</td>
            <td id="task-name{{count.value}}">{{s_name}}</td>
            <td id="task-cpu-percent{{count.value}}">{{s_cpu_percent}}</td>
            <td id="task-memory-percent{{count.value}}">{{s_memory_percent}}</td>
          </tr>
  {% set count.value = count.value + 1 %}
{% endfor %}
```

and then

```
 $("#task-pid"+i).text(task_status_pid[i]);
```

OR (recommended)

```js
const $tasks = $(".task-pid");

for(var i = 0; i< task_status_pid.length; i++){
  $tasks.eq(i).text(task_status_pid[i]);
   ....
}
```

using `<td class="task-pid"` etc

Comment: A little fix
`{% set count = 0 %}`
`{% set count = count + 1 %}`
to the first option
but it still doesn't update it

Comment: Please post the HTML that is generated and examples of the data.

Comment: Works perfectly fine.  the `{% set count = 0 %} {% set count = count + 1 %}` isn't good change it to this:
`{% set count = namespace(value=0) %}`
`{% set count.value = count.value + 1 %}`
`task-pid{{ count.value }}`

Comment: Yeah I had no idea to how to make a counter since I do not know the framework you are using

Comment: I still prefer the class version  - no need to mess with counters when creating and easier to update other fields from one field

Comment: I agree I'll change it to the class version. Thank you so much for the great answer